# Vue&TypeScript: 'el' property for vue-property-decorator/vue-class-component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Let this question will be laconic. Which equivalent for the below code will be for TypeScript & **Vue** && `vue-property-decorator` combination?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Comment: `const app: any = new Vue({ el: '#app',  data: { message: 'Hello Vue!' } as any } as any) as any`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) is intended to augment Vue components with class-style syntax in TypeScript. The code in question does not fit the criteria because it's not a component. Let's assume you meant to convert the script in this single-file-component:

*App.vue*:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The conversion with `vue-property-decorator` would look like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  message = 'Hello Vue!'
}
</script>
```

Mounting the root remains the same (`vue-property-decorator` would not be used):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app'
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

I recommend generating a TypeScript project with [`vue-cli`](https://cli.vuejs.org/) (*select the TypeScript preset and "class-style syntax" at the prompts*).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Upvote for explanations, examples, and your time. However, I strive to make initial html/css fully independent from JavaScript: first full render in browser without JS, and then Vue.js adds dynamics...